# Does Windows Kill Communication on Some Ports When Screensaver Kicks In?

Tags: windows, communication, ports, windows-screensaver

I have some trading software and noticed that signals weren't being sent to the broker whenever the screensaver was on.  Does Windows kill certain ports from communicating when the screensaver comes on?

Comment: I can't answer your question, but what port and what version of windows? What broker? If the 'broker' is a program instead of a windows service that would explain it. You could take a step towards investigating this yourself by running `TELNET <hostname> <port>` from an external computer to test.

Comment: I know that screensavers run under an entirely different desktop than the normal logged in user desktop. Maybe that freezes out any programs running on that desktop?